# Will the Google Drive appfolder be deleted after a user uninstalls my app?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) it sais: "Your App Folder is deleted if users uninstall your app from their Drive. They can also delete your app's App Folder manually using the Options menu in the Manage Apps dialog." but after I tried out to uninstall and reinstall the app and sync with `Drive.getDriveClient(...).requestSync();` I can access to the items I uploaded before. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling apps, can you see that storage is still consumed in the app data folder through the web interface?

**Here is the solution you may  trying:**

using `Drive.DriveApi.requestSync()` method in `onConnected()` method.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(syncCallBack);

    }
Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(syncCallBack);
private ResultCallback<Status> syncCallBack = new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                if (DriveStatusCodes.DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED == status.getStatusCode()) {
                    //intimate user to wait for some time if you want to
                }
            }
                //now query db file from google drive's app folder
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks. So it's a wrong statement in the documentation?

Comment: Because it would be stupid if the user backups his data to the app folder and after uninstall the backup is gone.